# Is there an Android chess GUI library

Tags: programming, android, open-source

I am looking for an open source chess gui library for Android that I can use in an app so that I don't need to take care of the GUI engine, but can focus on the logic behind it.

I have searched for solutions but not found anything. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can use mine. I have an Android application that takes care of the GUI elements.

https://github.com/jj30/ChessPGNHelper

The application itself is in the play store at

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bldg5.jj.pgnbase

Please attribute me (Jan Jansz) as a developer where possible. (I need it; thanks.)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing your works. I've forked your project and will take a look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything better than the active [Droidfish](http://web.comhem.se/petero2home/droidfish/) app.

Comment: The GUI is based on AWT, though, isn't it?

Comment: @barq I don't know. But it's definitely working and it's a very common GUI.